# Deformation Retract is an isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, deformation-theory, retraction

I wanna proof that if A is a derformation retract of $X$, then $(j)_*: \pi_1(A,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ which is induced by the inclusion $j:A \to X$ is an isomorphism for all $x_0 \in A$. I already proved that $(j)_*$ is injectiv but how to do it with the surjectivity? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

A deformation retraction is a special case of homotopy equivalence. I.e. we have a retraction $r:X\to A$ and the standard inclusion $j:A\to X$ such that

$$r\circ j= id_A$$
$$j\circ r\sim id_X$$

Note that in the first line we have literal equality, while in the second line homotopy (by assumption).

Now we simply apply $\pi_1$ functor to both sides and use the fact that it is homotopy invariant. This shows that $r_*$ and $j_*$ are inverses of each other, hence they are isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how to use the functor in the second line, can you help me out?

Comment: @PeterMinford Since $\pi_1$ is functorial, then $(id_X)_*=id_{\pi_1(X)}$. Since $\pi_1$ is homotopy invariant, then $(j\circ r)_*=id_{\pi_1(X)}$. Finally, again since $\pi_1$ is functorial, then $(j\circ r)_*=j_*\circ r_*$. All in all, second line implies $j_*\circ r_*=id_{\pi_1(X)}$.

Comment: I am sry but what do you mean with the homotopy invariant?

Comment: @PeterMinford if $f\sim g$ then $f_*=g_*$. This is the standard property of the fundamental group.

Comment: If $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$, then in general $j \circ r$ is not pointed homotopic to the identity. Your proof tacitly invokes "pointed homotopic".

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in other answers, this is implied by functoriality and the fact that homotopic maps induce the same map on the fundamental group.

We can on the other hand try a more elementary approach for surjectivity. Here, I’m using the notion of strong deformation retract. You don’t need this assumption.

Let $x_0 \in A$. Let $[\alpha] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$.

By definition, we have a homotopy $f_t:X \to X$ such that $f_0=id_X$, $f_t \mid_A=id$ and $f_1(X) = A$.

Now, this is telling you something very interesting. Indeed, $\alpha:S^1 \to X$ is a based loop, and we can see that we can define a new homotopy $g_t=f_t \circ \alpha$. Note that this is a *based* homotopy since $F_t(x_0)=x_0$ for all $t$ since $x_0 \in A$. Moreover, $g_1=f_1 \circ \alpha \subseteq A$, so in fact $[g_1] \in j_*(\pi_1(A))$ since $g_1$ is a loop in $A$. Moreover, since $g_t$ is a homotopy, we can see that $[g_1]=[\alpha]$ as desired.

Comment: You use that $A$ is a **strong** deformation retract of $X$. This is more restrictive than   a deformation retract.

Comment: True, I guess I just use a based homotopy. You’re right though, I always forget the various conventions that people use.

Comment: The result is nevertheless true for deformation retracts, but the proof is more sophisticated.

Comment: I agree. I mentioned that in an edit. Thanks for pointing out that this was different from what OP was after

Comment: $+1$@AndresMejia I think $\alpha:S^1 \to X$ is a based loop is wrong .It should be $\alpha:[0,1] \to X$

Comment: @jasmine same thing. Use the universal property of the quotient map $[0,1] \to S^1$ when compared to a "loop" $\alpha:[0,1] \to X$.