# Deformation Retract and surjectivity

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be a deformation retract of $X$ and $(j)_*: \pi_1(A,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ be the map induced by the inclusion map $j:A \to X$ (with $x_0 \in A$). I want now proof that for every $x \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$ there exists a $y \in \pi_1(A,x_0)$ s.t. $(j)_*([y])=x$.

Okay since $A$ is a deformation retract there exists a retraction $r: X \to A$ and we have that $r \circ j =id_A$ and $j \circ r \sim id_X$. But how to continue? Can somebody help me? 
(We don't know about functoriality yet and so we can't use it.)

Comment: A deformation retract is in particular a homotopy equivalence, and a homotopy-equivalence induces an isomorphism on all homotopy groups.

Comment: We can't use the functoriality here.. We don't saw this term

Comment: any $\alpha \colon I \to X$ is homotopic to $j\circ r(\alpha)$, in other words $[\alpha] = j_*([r\circ \alpha])$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deformation Retract is an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669168/deformation-retract-is-an-isomorphism)

Answer (score 0):

> Observe if $X,Y$ and $Z$ are topological space and $f:(X,x_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ and $g:(Y,y_0)\to (Z,z_0)$ are two continuous functions .
>   Then $(f \circ g) _*=f_*\circ g_*$.

We also know that $j \circ r \sim id_X \implies (j\circ r)*=(id_X)_* $

> I take $A$ to be a [**Strong deformation retract**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongDeformationRetract.html).  Then the homotopy relation $j \circ r \sim id_X$ is base point ($x_0\in A$) preserving.

---

> Suppose $f,g:(A,x_0)\to (X,x_0)$ and $f\sim g$ is basepoint preserving then there is a continuous map $F:[0,1]\times A \to X$
>   such that $F(0,x)=f(x)$, $F(1,x)=g(x)$ and $F(t,x_0)=x_0$ $\forall x \in A , t\in [0,1]$.

If $\gamma:[0,1]\to A$ is a loop in $A$ based at $x_0$ you show that $f\circ\gamma$ and $g\circ \gamma$ are path-homotopic as loop based at y_0 in $X$, i.e.
 $f\circ\gamma \sim g\circ \gamma$ and base point $(y_0)$ preserving, which implies  $[f\circ \gamma]$=$[g\circ \gamma]$.
Then you are done!

Define $G:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to X$ where $G(s,t)=F(s,\gamma(t))$

Observe $G(0,t)=F(0,\gamma(t))=f\circ \gamma(t)$, $G(1,t)=F(1,\gamma(t))=g\circ \gamma(t)$ and $G(s,0)=G(s,1)=y_0$

---

Hence here we have $$j_*\circ r_*=(j\circ r)*=(id_X)_*=id_{\pi_1(X,x_0)}(\text{Since  } j \circ r \sim id_X)$$
$$r_*\circ j_*=(r\circ j)*=(id_A)_*=id_{\pi_1(A,x_0)}(\text{Since  } r \circ j = id_A)$$
$\therefore j_*$ is an isomorphism.

---

Comment: I am not familiar with functors. I know this simple proof .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I undertand everything except the part: "$j \circ r \sim id_X \implies (j\circ r)*=(id_X)_* $". Why is this true? Sorry, I dont get it.

Comment: So do you know the fact that if $f\sim g$ then $f_*=g_*$?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Would it be okay if I attach a link where you can find the proof ?

Comment: Yeah of course, I hope I understand everything

Comment: Have you learnt path-homotopy?

Comment: Yes, we learnt path-homotopy

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope you understand it ! If you have doubts you have a look at the Chapter of Fundamental Group from "Topology" by James Munkres.

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: @Noobmathematician (This is about your edit.) You need to show that $f_*[\gamma]$ and $g_*[\gamma]$ are **path-homotopic**. That is, you're missing the conditions $G(s, 0) = f\circ\gamma(0)$ and $G(s, 1) = g\circ\gamma(1)$. (This actually a non-trivial fact).

Comment: $j \circ r \sim id_X \implies (j\circ r)*=(id_X)_* $ is only true if the homotopy is base-point preserving. This is not guaranteed unless $A$ is a **strong** retract of $X$.

Comment: @feyhat  Yes, you are right this thing is guaranteed iff we have the homotopy tobe base point preserving. Apologies I missed it.  so is it possible that the fact posed in the question might is not be true if $A$ is not a **strong** of $X$?

Comment: @PaulFrost may would it be possible for you to suggest me some edits so that it looks good?. , :) And thanks for you rectified me.

Comment: @Noobmathematician I suggest that you mention that your proof is only valid for strong deforrnations retracts. The result is also true for (non-strong) dedformations retracts, but the proof is much more complicated. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3465680.

Comment: @PaulFrost is it okay now ?

Comment: @Noobmathematician Yes, it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

If the homotopy between $j\circ r$ and $id_X$ can be taken to fix the basepoint (as in the case of a "strong" deformation retract) then you can argue as follows.

**Hint:** Since $j\circ r \sim id_X$, for any $Y$ and any continuous function $f\colon Y \to X$ we have $f \sim j\circ r\circ f$.

---

**Answer:** In order to prove surjectivity without using functoriality, notice that if you have any based loop $\alpha \colon I \to X$ then $\alpha = id_X\circ \alpha$ is homotopic to $j\circ r\circ \alpha$. In particular

$$[\alpha] = j_*([r\circ \alpha]) \in \pi_1(X, x_0) $$

and therefore $j_*\colon \pi_1(A, x_0) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ is surjective.

This simple argument can be adapted to prove something much more general: if $[Y, X]$ denotes the set of pointed homotopy classes of continuous functions and $h\colon A \to X$ is a pointed homotopy equivalence then the induced function $h_*\colon [Y, A] \to [Y, X]$ is a bijection for every $Y$ (for the fundamental group result let $Y=S^1$).

---

Alternatively, once you know functoriality (i.e. $(f\circ g)_* = f_* \circ g_*$) and homotopy-invariance ($f\sim g \implies f_* = g_*$) then surjectivity follows from formal set-theoretic properties as in Noob mathematician's answer.

Comment: Your argument is only true if the homotopy is base-point preserving. This is not guaranteed unless $A$ is a **strong** retract of $X$.

Comment: we need strong deformation retract